# How does request in Flask work in a multithreaded environment?

Tags: python, flask

I am a newbie to Flask 
In a multithreaded environment with multiple web requests what does the request object contain? Does it only work when one request is active at a time? (Assuming a single thread handles a single request)

Comment: This is very ambiguous indeed. A single thread may or may not handle a complete request depending on what the back end does. But if you're worrying about whether multiple concurrent requests can interfere with each other, that needn't be a concern (unless your server is getting hammered with traffic). In any case, if you're referring to the development server, this is all just academic because you will have paid attention to the multiple warnings not to use this in production.

Comment: assuming a single thread handles a complete request

Comment: We're still in the same position. Flask is not a server. How the _development_ server works should not really be a concern because you _really should_ use an actual proper server to serve the application. See: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/deploying/ . You can have `gunicorn` up and running with a single line of code.

Comment: For the `request` object, the documentation is [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#incoming-request-data)